# Unable to access gs_sh after installing GridDB on Ubuntu

Tags: griddb

I've installed GridDB on Ubuntu using dpkg as per the installation guide here: https://docs.griddb.net/gettingstarted/using-apt/#install-with-deb

I am able to change user to gsadm and to start and stop the service. However, when I try to access gs_sh to experiment with running some commands, I see the following:

```
jill@ubuntu-virtual-machine:~$ sudo su - gsadm
[sudo] password for jill: 
gsadm@ubuntu-virtual-machine:~$ gs_sh
gs_sh: command not found
```

When working as gsadm, the path is et as follows:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

I cannot locate the gs_sh command in any bi directory.

The package appears to have installed correctly; if I run dpkg -L griddb I get the following:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/griddb
/usr/griddb/bin
/usr/griddb-5.1.0
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/3rd_party
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/3rd_party/3rd_party.md
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/3rd_party/Apache_License-2.0.txt
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/3rd_party/BSD_License.txt
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/3rd_party/MIT_License.txt
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/3rd_party/MessagePack
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/3rd_party/MessagePack/COPYING
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/3rd_party/ebb
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/3rd_party/ebb/LICENSE
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/3rd_party/fletcher32_simd
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/3rd_party/fletcher32_simd/LICENSE
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/3rd_party/json-simple
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/3rd_party/json-simple/LICENSE.txt
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/3rd_party/omaha
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/3rd_party/omaha/COPYING
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/3rd_party/picojson
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/3rd_party/picojson/README.mkdn
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/3rd_party/purewell
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/3rd_party/purewell/purewell.txt
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/3rd_party/sha2
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/3rd_party/sha2/README
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/3rd_party/slf4j
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/3rd_party/slf4j/LICENSE.txt
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/3rd_party/slf4j/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/3rd_party/slf4j/slf4j-jdk14-1.7.7.jar
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/3rd_party/uuid
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/3rd_party/uuid/COPYING
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/3rd_party/yield
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/3rd_party/yield/yield.txt
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/3rd_party/zigzag_encoding
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/3rd_party/zigzag_encoding/LICENSE
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/bin
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/bin/gridstore
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/bin/gridstore-conf.jar
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/bin/gridstore.jar
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/bin/gs_adduser
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/bin/gs_deluser
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/bin/gs_joincluster
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/bin/gs_leavecluster
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/bin/gs_passwd
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/bin/gs_startnode
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/bin/gs_stat
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/bin/gs_stopcluster
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/bin/gs_stopnode
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/bin/gsserver
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/bin/log.py
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/bin/util.py
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/conf
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/conf/gridstore.conf
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/conf/gs_cluster.json
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/conf/gs_node.json
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/conf/initGsh
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/conf/password
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/conf_multicast
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/conf_multicast/gs_cluster.json
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/conf_multicast/gs_node.json
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/conf_multicast/password
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/docs
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/docs/README.md
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/docs/sample
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/docs/sample/program
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/docs/sample/program/Sample1.java
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/systemd
/usr/lib/systemd/system
/usr/lib/systemd/system/gridstore.service
/usr/share
/usr/share/java
/usr/bin/gs_adduser
/usr/bin/gs_deluser
/usr/bin/gs_joincluster
/usr/bin/gs_leavecluster
/usr/bin/gs_passwd
/usr/bin/gs_startnode
/usr/bin/gs_stat
/usr/bin/gs_stopcluster
/usr/bin/gs_stopnode
/usr/bin/gsserver
/usr/griddb/bin/gridstore
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/bin/gridstore-5.1.0.jar
/usr/griddb-5.1.0/bin/gridstore-conf-5.1.0.jar
/usr/share/java/gridstore-conf.jar
/usr/share/java/gridstore.jar
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

In summary, I ran the gs_sh command, which gave me a 'command not found' error. I expected to enter the gs shell so that I could run GridDb related commands